# границы (щели) разных размеров между элементами и группами элементов (с использованием сеток)

Tags: html, css, css3, grid

требуется разбить строку из 3*N (например, 9) следующим образом:

1. таблица имеет рамку шириной 3 пикселя
2. группы по 3 блока имеют между собой границу 2 пикселя
3. блоки внутри группы имеют между собой границу 1 пиксель

Через сетки я делаю следующим образом:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr/repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap:  2px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: black;
}

.cage {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr/repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cage div {
  display:  flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'table'>
  <div class = 'cage'>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class = 'cage'>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
  <div class = 'cage'>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Все замечательно, но...

**такой вопрос** - а можно ли ли как-то с помощью css сделать это не разбивая элементы на группы?

т.е. как то объяснить стилям правила для щелей

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr/repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: black;
}

.table div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'table'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Вариант `:nth-child(3n)` -  не подойдет?

Comment: @Node_pro, было бы идеально, если бы можно было бы обойтись как-то `gap`'ами не используя границ дочерних элементов, т.е. интересна возможность не трогать дочерний элемент вообще никак

Answer (score 2):

Да, с помощью псевдокласса nth-child(3n) . Где `3n` будет означать для каждого третьего.

https://jsfiddle.net/vdsn5kL4/

```
* {
        box-sizing:     border-box;
}

.table {
        display:              grid;
        grid-template:  1fr/repeat(9, 1fr);
    
    width:          300px;
    height:         50px;
    
    border:         3px solid black;
    background:     black;
}

.table div {
        display:                flex;
        justify-content:    center;
        align-items:          center;
    
    width:          100%;
    height:         100%;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    
    background:     white;
}

.table div:nth-child(3n) {
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.table div:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: да, решение хорошее, но это добавление новой сущности - границы, причем только одной у дочернего элемента, а можно ли как-то обойтись только свойствами сетки?

Comment: К сожалению никак, нет такого свойства у сетки

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, тогда это делается с помощью `nth-child(3n)`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr/repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: black;
}

.table div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.table div:nth-child(3n):not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'table'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: да, решение хорошее, но это добавление новой сущности - границы, причем только одной у дочернего элемента, а можно ли как-то обойтись только свойствами сетки?

Comment: @Zhihar, такого способа не знаю. Можете объяснить, чем плохи псевдоклассы?

Comment: да плохого нет, просто если до этого с помощью щелей формировался вид, то он никак не затрагивал дочерние элементы, а тут требуется именно менять уже свойства самих дочерних элементов